# Comment box in qTip disappears onfocus for IE/Edge browser with touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, qtip2

I am making use of an external JavaScript library [qTip](http://qtip2.com/). My application has a feature of 'StarRating' and 'Comments', which is provided through this plugin.
After providing a rating through the stars, one can enter the Comments(optional), which opens up in a dialog.

This scenario works well across all the major browsers i.e. Chrome FF and IE but not in IE (touch devices) and Edge browser (touch devices). As soon as the stars are clicked and on `focus` inside the input box, the dialog box disappears in the touch devices with IE and Edge only, but works well in Chrome and FF (touch enabled).

I don't know whether there is an issue with the library or with the touch events.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge doesn't support touch events by default. It has an alternative system called pointer events. Sometimes 3rd party libs implement touch based widgets that don't play well with pointers. A quick way to determine if this is the case is to switch on touch events inside of Edge. Put about:flags in the address bar then go to the setting enable touch event and change it to always.

If the site now works, then I suspect it's an issue with the library. If that is the issue then I'd raise the issue with qTip they can probably help identify the issue specifically so that it can be fixed in the library.

Comment: What about IE browser on touch devices. I tried `about:flags` in the address bar on IE browser but it showed 'Navigation to the webpage was canceled'. Any idea about this?

Comment: That about flags is Edge only. IE doesn't have support at all for touch events. Only pointer events.

Comment: Ok.Is there any other way that one can enable the touch events on IE somehow?